# Do registration bots detect label text before a text input to figure out what the text input is for?

Tags: bots, registration, spam-prevention, user-registration, honeypot

I have looked at some ways to fool registration bots.  One method suggested is to change the text input names/ids to fool the registration bots.  I am considering changing the names/ids of my text inputs to fool the registration bots.  However, if registration bots are sophisticated enough to look at the preceding label text before a text input, then there is no point in changing the name/id of the text input because the registration bots will use the label text instead to determine what the following text input really is for.

For example, consider this snippet of HTML where I have changed the text input name/id to "abc" in an attempt to fool the registration bot:

```
<td>E-mail</td><td><input type="text" id="abc" name="abc">
```

Would registration bots know the above text input with name/id that is "abc" is actually a text input for e-mail because it is preceded by the E-mail label?  If registration bots that look at the text input don't know what it is based on the name/id, but can then figure out what the text input is really for after looking at the preceding label text, then changing the name/id won't be able to fool registration bots.

Answer (score 0):

Registration bots vary in complexity. What you are proposing is just another way to try and fool more complex bots. But, if someone wants to make a bot specifically for your site, you won't be able to fool it with this.

Keep in mind a basic bot will simply look at inputs and fill them out looking at their types.

Take a look at this SO answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36227377/7919626

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was just wondering whether its a common feature for registration bots to inspect the label before a text input, rather than rely on the text input name/id.

Of course if somebody makes a bot specifically for my site, I won't be able to fool it.  But if the majority of registration bots do look at the labels before a text input, that's something I have to account for in the design of my registration page.